# Load table view cell with edit options showing by default at initial launch of table view

Tags: ios, xcode, tableview, swift4

I want to show table view cell showing edit options by default without applying swipe at the initial launch of the table view. I have tried setting `tableView.edit` actions property to true but it is not **swiping the cell**. It is only showing a delete button with action set to swipe. I want to perform swipe automatically at **viewDidLoad()**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there is no way to do that. Apple doesn't provide an edit mode on the `UITableViewCell`. Whereas UITableView has it.

Maybe there is a workaround for the problem you are trying to solve.

In one of the problems, I had where we wanted to let our users know that the table view cell has actions on top of them. What we did was added a custom view on top of the cell and did some animations to show the user actions.

Comment: Cool.. That is what i did in my project.